# Can we call any view in java page without calling its id?

Tags: java, android, view

Is their any way by which we can call imageview or any other such view on java page without assigning it id?

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: `parentView.getChildAt(index of you view);`

Answer (score 0):

You can have `Tag` Assigned to the `View` if you want to call it without `findViewById(id)`

```
view_row.findViewWithTag(tag)
```

Although it is Not Recommended as Usual

Hope this could help...